# Show/Hide issue when page loads or refreshed

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am using the exact code seen here:

http://gazpo.com/downloads/tutorials/html5/contentEditable/

As you can see, when the grey box is clicked the save button appears
however after using this exact code on my own site when the page loads
or is refreshed the save button is shown. After clicking somewhere on 
the screen (other than the grey box) it is hidden.

Can anyone think of a reason why it is initially showing?

I am pretty new to jquery.

My code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#save").click(function (e) {         
        var content = $('#editable').html();    

        $.ajax({
            url: 'save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            content: content
            },              
            success:function (data) {

                if (data == '1')
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html("Data received successfully.")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("error")
                    .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
            }
        });   

    });

    $("#editable").click(function (e) {
        $("#save").show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#save").hide();  
    });

});

  </script>

  <body>

                                    <div id="status"></div>
                <div id="content3">
                <div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
                </div>
                <button id="save">Save</button>
                </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#status{
display:none;
margin-bottom:15px;
padding:5px 10px;
border-radius:5px;
}

#save{
display: none;
margin: 5px 10px 10px;
}

#content3{
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Adding an overriding style solves the problem...just not sure why the css isn't doing the job

```
    <button id="save" style="display:none;">Save</button>
```

Comment: Can't view your site but a guess would be to add `style="display:none;"` to the save button if you want it to initially be hidden.

Comment: Does your CSS styles have for **#save** id the attribute **display:none;** ??

Comment: can you show your code. Are you using the exact same code?

Comment: Thanks Danny that'll work. Just wondering why it's not working with the original code.

Comment: You are not including CSS link tag anywhere in html. So, no initial hiding for the poor button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick inspection tells me that the button has a default CSS style of `display:none;` before JQuery ever even gets ahold of it. That style comes from the head of the document.

After somewhere on the page is clicked, then the JQuery triggers, applying either `display:none;` or `display:inline;` to the button, depending on the target of the click. This is added to the `style` attribute of the element itself, overriding the style from the document head.

As a side note, this is often done to prevent the element from briefly appearing on the screen before any Javascript has a chance to run and hide it.

Comment: Adding an overiding style="display:none;" to the html does the trick although this is already declared in my css??

Comment: `display:none;` should always work, so if it's not hiding the button in your external CSS but is working when applied inline, your external CSS must not be getting applied somehow. Maybe an invalid selector, or a more specific selector somewhere is getting in the way, or the sheet is not attached properly. Either way, I am confident that the JQuery is not the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm.. I didn't read your question all the way thru.  Sorry.

**Edit:**

I'm posting the final answer here to avoid being down voted for a 3rd time...
The original code, provided in your link has a css style applied to the save button display:none;

In your code (at least what you have provided) you do not have any css style applied to your save button, so initially it will show up.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that... it is intended to do so. But when the page is loaded it should be hidden UNTIL the screen is clicked. The example link does this, however after copying the code to my own website the save button shows when the page loads(without clicking on the document)

Comment: That's because of CSS. There's a style in the example for #save which starts it as display:none;